# ng-bs-daterangepicker not working with latest version of bootstrap-daterangeicker

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this multi-calendar selector: https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker which uses the jquery plugin: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

However, I would like to have ability to configure to show either one or two calendar controls; right now it's always displays two calendar controls.

The latest version of bootstrap-daterangepicker allows to configure to select only one date, but this the directive wrapper ng-bs-daterangepicker hasn't been updated to provide that functionality.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I wasn't using the latest version of CSS for the plugin.